# What is the use of reshape() function in glut?

Tags: c, opengl

How is the `reshape()` function working in this code and how is it getting its parameter from `glutReshapeFunc(reshape)` without any parameter in reshape of `glutReshapeFunc(reshape)`?
What is the value of `int x`, `int y` in `void keyboard (unsigned char key, int x, int y)` function?

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

static int year = 0, day = 0;

void init(void) 
{
   glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   glShadeModel (GL_FLAT);
}

void display(void)
{
   glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   glColor3f (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

   glPushMatrix();
   glutWireSphere(1.0, 20, 16);   /* draw sun */
   glRotatef ((GLfloat) year, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
   glTranslatef (2.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   glRotatef ((GLfloat) day, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
   glutWireSphere(0.2, 10, 8);    /* draw smaller planet */
   glPopMatrix();
   glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape (int w, int h)
{
   glViewport (0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h); 
   glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity ();
   gluPerspective(60.0, (GLfloat) w/(GLfloat) h, 1.0, 20.0);
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();
   gluLookAt (0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
}

void keyboard (unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
   switch (key) {
      case `d':
         day = (day + 10) % 360;
         glutPostRedisplay();
         break;
      case `D':
         day = (day - 10) % 360;
         glutPostRedisplay();
         break;
      case `y':
         year = (year + 5) % 360;
         glutPostRedisplay();
         break;
      case `Y':
         year = (year - 5) % 360;
         glutPostRedisplay();
         break;
      default:
         break;
   }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   glutInit(&argc, argv);
   glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
   glutInitWindowSize (500, 500); 
   glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
   glutCreateWindow (argv[0]);
   init ();
   glutDisplayFunc(display); 
   glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
   glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
   glutMainLoop();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  Also, please avoid SMS-ese such as 'thanku', and you don't need to introduce yourself (your posts are tagged with your name).

Comment: The values of x and y is the position of the mouse at the time the keyboard is pressed. https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node49.html

Answer (score 8):

It appears that the `glutReshapeFunc()` function takes a pointer to a function; presumably, in fact, it is declared as something somewhat similar to:

```
void glutReshapeFunc(void (*function)(int x, int y));
```

Similarly, `glutDisplayFunc()` takes another pointer to a function, and `glutKeyboardFunc()` also takes a pointer to a function.  When a function is specified by name without the function call parentheses after it, it reduces to 'pointer to a function' (or you can think of a bare function name as a pointer to the function body, like a bare array name is a pointer to the start of the array).

You'd have to read the manual to discover the purpose of the `x` and `y` parameters to the `keyboard()` function.  They aren't used by the code shown.  They are likely the position of something, but which something is less than clear without reading the manual.

Answer (score 6):

`reshape` and `keyboard` functions are used as so called *callbacks*. You're giving GLUT pointers to those functions, GLUT keeps those pointers and calls those function, with parameters, at the times as specified in the GLUT documentation.

About like that:

```
void (*display_callback)(void);
void (*reshape_callback)(int, int);
void (*keyboard_callback(unsigned char, int, int);
/* ... */

void eventloop(...)
{
    while(...) {
        if( keyboard_event )
              keyboard_callback(keyboard_event->key, mouse_x, mouse_y);

        if( window_reshaped )
              reshape_callback(window->width, window->height);

        if( needs_redraw )
              display_callback();
    }
}
```

Now regarding what's done in the reshape callback: *Everything* that's placed there in *beginner* tutorials is actually much better done in the display function. Setting the viewport, setting the projection I mean. Later you'll probably want to draw a HUD, some text or a minimap, or a split view. And once you've reached that point, a reshape function doing viewport and projection setup becomes a liability. So get rid of it now.

```
void display(void)
{
   int const w = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
   int const h = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);

   glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   glColor3f (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

   glViewport (0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h); 
   glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity ();
   gluPerspective(60.0, (GLfloat) w/(GLfloat) h, 1.0, 20.0);

   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();
   gluLookAt (0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

   glPushMatrix();
   glutWireSphere(1.0, 20, 16);   /* draw sun */
   glRotatef ((GLfloat) year, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
   glTranslatef (2.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   glRotatef ((GLfloat) day, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
   glutWireSphere(0.2, 10, 8);    /* draw smaller planet */
   glPopMatrix();

   glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be a direct answer to this question. 
The *reshape* function is a *call back* function which is called whenever size or shape of the application window changes. Reshape function takes 2 arguments,they are *width* and *height* of reshaped window. Mainly these parameters are used to set a new *viewport*.